# Deriving generating function for total number of individuals in branching process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am working on the following exercise.

> A branching process $(X_n:n\geq 0)$ has $\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)=1$. Let the total number of individuals in the first $n$ generations of the process be $Z_n$, with probability generating function $Q_n$. Prove that, for $n\geq2$, $$Q_n(s)=sP_1(Q_{n-1}(s)),$$ where $P_1$ is the probability generating function of the amount of offspring for every family.

I tried, everything, writing it out, using the definition of pgf's, partitioning the expectation, looking up a proof, etc. I found a paper from Good (1949) *The number of individuals in a cascade process*, but I can't access it via my university. According to another paper, that just states this result, Good proved it. Also, the problem seems quite elementary but I don't get how to solve it.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT** Using @DhruvKohli-expiTTp1z0's initial post, the brute force approach, I also tried working this out myself. The base case is clear: $$Q_2(s)=\mathbb{E}(s^{z_2})=\mathbb{E}(s^{x_0+x_1})=\mathbb{E}(s^{x_0}s^{x_1})=\mathbb{E}(s\cdot s^{x_1})=s\mathbb{E}(s^{x_1})=s(P_1(s))^1=sP_1(s)),$$ because $X_1$ is just the amount of offspring created by generation zero, having only 1 member. Now observe that $$Q_1(s)=\mathbb{E}(s^{z_1})=\mathbb{E}(s^{x_0})=\mathbb{E}(s^1)=s,$$ so that $$Q_2(s)=sP_1(s)=sP_1(Q_1(s)).$$ This establishes the base case. So now assume that for an $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the assertment $Q_n(s)=sP_1(Q_{n-1}(s))$ is true. $$\begin{align}
Q_{n+1}(s)&=\mathbb{E}(s^{z_{n+1}})=\mathbb{E}(s^{z_n}s^{x_n})\\
&=\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\cdots\mathbb{E}}_{{n \  \text times}}(s^{z_n}s^{x_n}|x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\cdots)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(s^{Z_n}(\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\cdots\mathbb{E}}_{{n-1 \  \text times}}(s^{x_n}|x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\cdots)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(s^{Z_n}(\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\cdots\mathbb{E}}_{{n-2 \  \text times}}(P_1(s)^{X_{n-1}}|x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2})\cdots)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(s^{Z_{n-1}}(\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\cdots\mathbb{E}}_{{n-2 \  \text times}}((sP_1(s))^{X_{n-1}}|x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2})\cdots)\\
& \ \ \vdots\\
&=\underbrace{sP_1(sP_1(sP_1(\cdots(sP_1(s)\cdots)}_{n \ \text{times}}\\
&=sP_1[\underbrace{sP_1(sP_1(sP_1(\cdots(sP_1(s)\cdots)}_{n-1 \ \text{times}}]\\
&=sP_1(Q_n(s))\\
\end{align}$$

So if the statement is true for an $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is also true for $n+1\in\mathbb{N}$. Because the statement is true for $n=2\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows by induction that the statement is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\ \backslash\{1\}$.

**Is this proof valid? Can someone verify it?**

I know that @DhruvKohli-expiTTp1z0's is better, but this brute force approach seems like the only proof I could come up with myself. Also, I know that still not all the details in the above proof are provided, but the idea is in there without being cumbersome, I think.

Comment: I don't understand the point of having many expectations. As I see it, 

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[s^{Z_n+X_n}] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{Z_n+X_n}|X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_n}\mathbb{E}[s^{X_n}|X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_n}P_{1}(s)^{X_{n-1}}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n-1}}(sP_{1}(s))^{X_{n-1}}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n-1}}(sP_{1}(s))^{X_{n-1}}|X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_{n-2}]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n-1}}P_1(sP_{1}(s))^{X_{n-2}}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n-2}}(sP_1(sP_{1}(s)))^{X_{n-2}}]
\end{align*}$$

 and so on.

Comment: Anyway, I personally don't like the way induction hypothesis is used in the end but I can't see any other way to use it. Everything else seems fine to me. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I was thinking we needed the multiple expectations because we conditoned on $n$ variables but now I think about it I don't really see why it's necessary either. Thanks a lot for the verification and your answer, this really helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $Z_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_i$,

As per the comment by @Did,

$$Z_{n} = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{X_1}A^{(i)}_{n-1}$$

where $X_1 \perp A^{(i)}_{n-1}$ and $A^{(i)}_{n-1}$ and $Z_{n-1}$ have same distribution. The intuition is that the number of individuals in $n$ generations starting with $m$ individuals will (in a probabilistic sense) equal $m$ times the number of individuals in $n$ generations starting with a single individual.

$$Q_{n}(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{Z_{n}}|X_1]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{1+\sum_{i=1}^{X_1}A^{(i)}_{n-1}}|X_{1}]] = \mathbb{E}[sQ_{n-1}(s)^{X_1}] = sP_{1}(Q_{n-1}(s))$$

Comment: The recursion to use is
$$Z_{n} = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{Z_1}A^{(i)}_{n-1}$$

Comment: That does give the desired expression to be proved. I thought that $Z_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. By your definition $Z_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_i$. I am updating my answer.

Comment: The "thought" in your comment is not even related to my comment, which is only taking the branching mechanism seriously.

Comment: Okay I understand now, what I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand what you and @Did mean, but I'm not completely sure. Could you explain in more detail what exactly $A_{n-1}^i$ means? Also, I think that the brute force approach, that you deleted, is quite intuitive. Why did you delete that? Is that approach wrong?

Comment: And what do you mean here by $\perp$? I know that the symbol is used for orthogonality but you don't mean that here right? Is it used to denote independence?

Comment: Suppose that the first individual (corresponding to $X_0=1$) produces $X_1$ offsprings. Then, each of these offspring starts an independent branching process.  $A_{n-1}^{(i)}$ is the number of individuals in the subsequent $n-1$ generations of the $i$th offspring including the $i$th offspring. By the definition/mechanism of Branching process $A^{(i)}_{n-1}$ has the same distribution as $Z_{n-1}$. $\perp$ means independent. I didn't like the brute force approach but you can still verify the result with it. Probably, a solution using induction is possible. You may try working out the details.

Comment: Okay, thanks, this is clear. I will accept your answer and try working out the induction step. If it works out well I will also include that in the question with an edit.

Comment: @DhruvKohli-expiTTp1z0's: I included a proof by induction. Would you mind to take a look at it and verify it or comment what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to write the left handside as an expectation by definition, then use tower property and condition upon $Z_{n-1} $.  I am only with the phone so will write more details later if needed.

Comment: Thanks, your idea is what is worked out in the other answer right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Maybe the conditioning is upon $Z_1$, and not $Z_{n-1}$, so perhaps my answer was not even correct

Comment: I think so too. Before asking the question I tried conditioning upon $Z_{n-1}$ but it didn't work out (for me at least).